# Error on setting CORS header for API Gateway lambda authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have a lambda authorizer for my API Gateway authorization. When authorizer returns 401 or 403 I do not get CORS back in response header. I am using `AWS::Serverless::Api` resource, and after some research found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-gatewayresponses) that I need to set `GatewayResponses` to return custom headers for 4XX responses.

My Api Gateway definition looks like:

```
resApiGateway:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
Properties:
  StageName: !Sub "${env}"
  EndpointConfiguration: !If [IsLocal, "REGIONAL", "EDGE"]
  Cors:
    AllowMethods: "'OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE'"
    AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization'"
    AllowOrigin: "'*'"
  GatewayResponses:
    DEFAULT_4XX:
      ResponseParameters:
        "gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "'*'"
  ...
  ...
```

But I am getting error on cfn stack deployment:

```
Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [resApiGateway] is invalid. Invalid gateway response parameter 'gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

Comment: Have you tried [this syntax?](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_gateway_responses/template.yaml)  (With `Headers:` under `ResponseParameters`)

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you @MikePatrick. Please put it in answers so I can accept.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This feature was released with SAM v1.11.0.  The [release notes](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/releases/tag/v1.11.0) have a link to [this sample application template](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_gateway_responses/template.yaml), which demonstrates the feature.

Unfortunately, Amazon's own SAM documentation (which you linked to) only points you toward their [OpenAPI extension docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-gateway-responses.html).

These docs seem to show how you would configure API Gateway to use this feature with an OpenAPI specification, rather than with a SAM template.

---

To specify `GatewayResponses` in your SAM template, use the syntax found in the sample application:

```
Resources:
  restApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      GatewayResponses:
        DEFAULT_4XX:
          ResponseParameters:
            Headers:
              Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this! I have been searching for this for hours!! The linked sample application code is also 404 now. I ended up there from release notes but hit a dead end because of 404 until I saw your response here with an example yml snippet.

Comment: I'm still receiving an error when this is configured: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: On Angular I was receiving 0 as status code and with this it solved my issue. Cheers mate!